# RestKit 0.23.3: mapping same key twice (or even more often) does not work

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

Have not found this case in any of the RestKit documentation so far, so I guess it just does not work:

This mapping, where I'm using the key "theText" twice

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DummyText class]];
 [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                     @"theText": @"title",
                                                     @"theText": @"label",
                                                     @"somethingElse": @"yesSomethingElse"
                                                     }];
```

will return a successfully mapped DummyText object, but only with title filled with the value from the key "theText", but label is nil.

Is there a way, how I can fill a key's value into multiple destination attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the mapping actually raised an exception if you try to configure it like that...

Anyway, you can create a custom accessor method on your destination class and use the mapping to call that accessor method, then, in that method, set your 2 variables.

Comment: The issue is, that I can't generally map the two whenever the one is set, but I only wanted it to be mapped through that REST interface to both. As however I can't see any other solution, I'll flag this as accepted answer.